# How to deal with assembly and DLLs in DLL hell?

Tags: c#, dll, version, assemblyinfo

I am working on two DLLs, being called by an application. Everything is programmed in C#.
Recently I've tried to work with pre-build events, in order to add some versioning information to the DLLs. I have removed all that work: in GIT, all files (project files, source files, AssemblyInfo.cs) are present in GIT and there are all changes are deleted. There are just some leftovers (like `FixedAssemblyInfo.cs` files and `AssemblyInfo_Orig.cs`), but those are not referred to in the project files.

In order to work with the DLLs, I build them into a `Modules` directory and I use `Application_Server.exe` as an external program for running the DLL. That application is the same for both DLLs.

When I try to work with DLL1, everything is working fine.
When I try to work with DLL2, I have the following weird error message:

Source code (`source_file.cs`):

```
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
...
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(base.GetType());
```

Error message (`Exception` thrown):

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 
'Could not load file or assembly 'Application_Server.XmlSerializers,
                                  Version=1.0.0.0, ...' or one of its dependencies. 
The system cannot find the file specified.'
```

Why is this strange?

1. `source_file.cs` belongs to `DLL1`, not to `DLL2` (and I'm busy working with `DLL2`).
2. When I launch `DLL1` (which launches the same external application as `DLL2`), everything is working fine.

Anybody has an idea why `DLL2` does not want to refer to `System.xml.dll`, and this in a source file of `DLL1` while that same `DLL1` does not have that problem?

Thanks in advance

**Edit: Process Explorer results:**
I just ran Process Explorer (while debugging `DLL2` in Visual Studio, having the `Exception`'s error message open): apparently `Application_Server.exe` has `System.XML.dll` loaded.

**Edit: callstack:**
Hereby the (partial) callstack when the `Exception` occurs:

```
 mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(System.Reflection.AssemblyName fileName, string codeBase, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly locationHint, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark, System.IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, bool throwOnFileNotFound, bool forIntrospection, bool suppressSecurityChecks) Line 1951    C#
 mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyRef, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, ref System.Threading.StackCrawlMark stackMark, System.IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, bool throwOnFileNotFound, bool forIntrospection, bool suppressSecurityChecks) Line 1859    C#
 mscorlib.dll!System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(System.Reflection.AssemblyName assemblyRef) Line 363    C#
 System.Xml.dll!System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.LoadGeneratedAssembly(System.Type type, string defaultNamespace, out System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializerImplementation contract)    Unknown
 System.Xml.dll!System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.XmlSerializer(System.Type type, string defaultNamespace)    Unknown
 System.Xml.dll!System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.XmlSerializer(System.Type type)    Unknown
>Application_Server.dll!Application_Server.Communication.Messagess.Message.ToString() Line 123    C#
```

**Edit: Project properties "Build" tabpage**
My Project's "Build" properties page looks as follows (both for `DLL1` and `DLL2`):

[image]

(As that modification does not solve the issue, I've decided to remove it.)

**Important edit: modification of bad reference**
In `DLL1`, there was a reference to an older version of `DLL2`. I have replaced that reference with a reference to the current `DLL2` but that did not solve the issue (I've been checking the entries in the `.FileListAbsolute.txt` in order to be sure).

Comment: It has nothing to do with `System.xml.dll` but with the fact that when you are using `XmlSerializer` i may produce serialization assemblies (with sgen.exe) ... you may disable this (at least in .NET framework) with seting project option `GenerateSerializationAssemblies` to `Off`

Comment: But it seems like a `Application_Server` has this option on (it wants to load `Application_Server.XmlSerializers` )

Comment: You have disabled that for the configuration you actually use?

Comment: I have disabled it for both DLLs, I don't have access to the source code of the executable.

Comment: I can open the `Application_Server.exe` in Process Explorer. Can I see in any way if that property is set or not?

Comment: @Selvin: I've updated my answer. Any more ideas?

Comment: @Ralf: I've updated my answer. Any more ideas?